# Modify beaconing in a VANET project

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am new in Veins simulation and I did the Tic Toc tutorial for the OMNeT++'s work. I need to change the beaconing between nodes and Rsu in a Veins, sumo and OMNeT interaction.

I work with OMNeT 5.4.1, SUMO 0.30.0 and Veins 4.7.1.

I want to make the implementation of a function that change the frequency of beaconing due the number of nodes, but this nodes are generated by TraCIScenarioManagerLaunched and I don't know how access to the parameters of this nodes.

I'm working in a network created by me that is a extended of network call Scenario.ned.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
auto hosts = manager->getManagedHosts();
for(auto h: hosts){
    YOUCLASS* o = FindModule<YOUCLASS*>::findSubModule((h.second));
    o.beaconInterval = X;
}
```

The first line gives you all available hosts in the network.
While the list of hosts is iterated you can use `FindModule` to search for the module to set your beacon rate.

However, this approach highly depends on your implementation.